# How to inject a specific implementation in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mocking

I have a Repository which has a dependency of `User`

I need to put other implementation of `User` and I can do it like that, but with this approach I do not know how to mock my repository

```
private readonly IRepository<Entity> _repository;

public SomeClass(MyAppDbContext context)
{
  _repository= new EfRepository<WorkOrder>(context, new User());
}
```

Is there a way to inject a specific implementation of `User` here, or how I can test the code I wrote

Comment: There is some confusion here. Is the user a run-time data or a service?

Comment: Reference [Dependency Injection Code Smell: Injecting runtime data into components](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as you inject `MyAppDbContext` into `SomeClass` you can also inject an instance of `User`, e.g.

```
private readonly IRepository<Entity> _repository;

public SomeClass(MyAppDbContext context, User user)
{
  _repository= new EfRepository<WorkOrder>(context, user);
}
```

You can either register `User` in the IoC like this:

```
services.AddTransient<User>();
```

In case you have already registered a service for `User` and want to use another instance, you can register a factory method for `SomeClass` that sets up the `User` instance:

```
services.AddScoped<SomeClass>(prov => new SomeClass(
  prov.GetRequiredService<MyAppDbContext>(), 
  new User()));
```

The factory method approach is viable if you only have a few spots that need the special instance, otherwise you can use this approach:
Unlike other IoCCs, the .NET Core IoCC does not support named registrations, but you can also use some kind of "marker interface" to register another instance:

```
public interface ISpecialUser : IUser {}

public class User : IUser
{
  // ...
}

public class AnotherUser : ISpecialUser
{
  // ...
}

// ...
public SomeClass(MyAppDbContext context, ISpecialUser user)
{
  _repository= new EfRepository<WorkOrder>(context, user);
}


// ...
services.AddScoped<IUser, User>();
services.AddScoped<ISpecialUser, AnotherUser>();
```

In the tests, you can set up an instance of `User` that suits your needs and use the new constructor parameter.

Comment: I have already a service `User` registered, but I want to inject a different user
`services.AddScoped(typeof(IUser), typeof(OneUser));`
`services.AddScoped(typeof(IUser), typeof(AnotherUser));`
Now I have two implementations of the same interface, how to inject a specific one?

Comment: @RheinmetallSkorpion you can use the factory method approach or a "marker interface"; I've clarified the answer.